# Реализовать функцию s/(s+1) при помощи блоков simulink

Tags: matlab

[image: Структурная схема систем c инерционной гибкой обратной связи и без нее]

См. рис. можно уведеть как в схеме задействован блок реализующий функ. вида s/(s+1), однако я не могу найти даного блока в стандартной бибилиотеке simulink. Есть блок Transfer Fcn, однако он реализует функ. вида 1/(s+1). Где найти или как можно реализовать блок реализующий функ. вида s/(s+1)?

Быстро не удалось найти данный блок в стандартной библиотеке, в гугл-поисковике толком ничего конкретного. ЧатGPT рекомендовал 3-ри варианта, 2-ва я отбросил, а последний заключаеться в подсоединениие на вход Transfer Fcn блока Integrator, но я не уверен что это правильный ответ.

Comment: p.s.: скриншот сделан из методических указаний, я предполагаю что только из-за незнанее как реализовать этот блок я получаю не корректный результат на выходе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё делается в блоке Transfer Fcn. Числитель вашей передаточной функции можно записать, как 0,1*s+0, тогда вектор коэффициентов будет [0.1 0], его и надо вписать в соответствующее поле.

К ChatGPT в таких случаях лучше не обращайтесь, он может составлять осмысленные тексты, но математические задачи решает из рук вон плохо.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!